# Insert image in parse.com don't works with class user

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I'm triyng to insert an image in the defined class user of parse.com but don't works and return error 400 bad request.With another class it function perfectly!!

```
       $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
headers: {'X-Parse-Application-Id':'qS0KLMx5h9lFL*hM9EEPiTS3VMk','X-Parse-REST-API- 

 Key':'nh3eoUo9G*VQzvbF2gMhcKJIfIt1Gm','Content-Type': 'application/json'},
url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User/",
data: '{"name" : "An Image", "image" : {"name" : '+"\""+"b3b47ce2-62dc-4861-a0ad- 
   79cfffe9b07a-foto ste.jpg"+"\""+', "__type" : "File"}}',


 contentType: "application/json",

 success: function(data) {
      console.log(data );

    },
    error: function(data) {

      console.log("ko" );
    }





     });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid request. You're sending a POST to the users endpoint. POSTs will create new objects; to sign up a user, you would need to pass a username and password.

If instead you wish to update an existing user, then you should use PUT and append the user's object id to the end of the URL: https://api.parse.com/1/users/{objectId}